# Объеденение SQL запросов, которые отличаются на два условия

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Пользователь когда заходит в свой профиль, он должен получать все свои продукты(активные и не активные, у которых истек и не истек срок размещения), а когда заходит в профиль другого пользователя он должен получать только активные товары и те у которых срок размещения еще не истек.

Например

При этом условии я получаю свои товары:

```
const user_id = 2; // в чей профиль я захожу
const decodedUserId = 2; // мой ид
```

При этом условии я получаю товары другого пользователя:

```
const user_id = 5; // в чей профиль я захожу
const decodedUserId = 2; // мой ид
```

Как проверяю на чей профиль я зашел:

```
let products;
if (user_id == decodedUserId) {
    products = (await db.query(UserProduct.getMerchantAllProductsByIdForUser(user_id))).rows;
} else {
    products = (await db.query(UserProduct.getMerchantProductsByIdForUser(user_id))).rows;
}
```

```
class UserProduct {
    static getMerchantProductsByIdForUser(user_id) {
        const sql = `SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, P.PRODUCT_NAME, P.ORIGINAL_PRICE, P.USER_ID
                FROM PRODUCTS AS P
                        WHERE 
                            P.END_DATE >= NOW() 
                            AND P.ACTIVE = TRUE
                            AND P.USER_ID = '${user_id}'`;
        return sql;
    }

    static getMerchantAllProductsByIdForUser(user_id) {
        const sql = `SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, P.PRODUCT_NAME, P.ORIGINAL_PRICE, P.USER_ID
                FROM PRODUCTS AS P
                        WHERE 
                            P.USER_ID = '${user_id}'`;
        return sql;
    }
}

export default UserProduct;
```

Можно ли как то объединить эти два sql запроса? Чтобы я вызывал одну функцию, а не проверял равен ли мой ид тому на чей я проходу и в зависимости от этого вызывал определенную функцию. А в sql запросе проверять, если `user_id` равен полю `P.USER_ID` в таблице `PRODUCTS`, то выводить все продукты (активные и не активные, у которых истек и не истек срок размещения), а если не равен то выводить только активные товары и те у которых срок размещения еще не истек.

```
const products = (await db.query(UserProduct.getMerchantAllProductsByIdForUser(user_id))).rows;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, 
       P.PRODUCT_NAME, 
       P.ORIGINAL_PRICE, 
       P.USER_ID,
       (P.END_DATE >= NOW() AND P.ACTIVE = TRUE) `in both queries?` 
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
WHERE P.USER_ID = '${user_id}
```

Comment: `in both queries?` Мне не нужно возвращать не активные товары и те у которых истек срок размещения для пользователя 5, а для пользователя 2 нужно, так как это мои товары

Comment: @MegaRoks 1) Запись, которую вернёт первый запрос, будет гарантированно возвращена и вторым запросом. Вот тебе и формируется признак, оба запроса вернут её или только второй. А дальше уже в коде фильтруй по нему как нужно - в зависимости там от ID юзера или ещё как. 2) Ты хотел объединить запросы? Я объединил - строго в той форме, в какой они у тебя в коде. Если нужно не то - значит, это у тебя исходные данные косые.